# Are Activity and Service running in the same thread?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I am having some confusion in basic concepts of Handler, service and activity. I have seen in many places mentioning that **service runs in the UI thread**. I have a couple of questions regarding this statement.

- Is above statement true or false??
- Can someone explain this statement from android reference for Service

> A Service is not a thread. It is not a means itself to do work off of the main thread (to avoid Application Not Responding errors).
>
> If service runs in UI thread then it is not suitable for heavy work. True/False ??
>
> If there is no activity running then in which thread service will be running?? if the above statement is true.
>
> If the above statement is true? then If I declare Handler in service as well as activity what would happen?? because a single Thread has one instance of Handler.
>
> Forgive me if the questions are too noob.

Comment: Proof of concept: start an activity, and from its onCreate method, start a service, and in the service's onStartCommand, call SystemClock.sleep(10000); Observe that the activity can't proceed while the sleep is happening within the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is above statement true or false?

No object "runs" on a thread, anywhere in Java. *Methods* run on threads.

Hence, a more accurate statement is that the lifecycle methods on `Service` -- `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, and `onDestroy()` -- are called on the main application thread.

> Can someone explain this statement from android reference for Service

I don't know how to explain that much better than it is written. While a `Service` *can manage* a background thread, a `Service` is not *itself* a `Thread`.

> If service runs in UI thread then it is not suitable for heavy work

No object "runs" on a thread, anywhere in Java. *Methods* run on threads.

Hence, a more accurate statement is that you should not take much time in work directly triggered by the aforementioned lifecycle methods.

> If there is no activity running then in which thread service will be running?

No object "runs" on a thread, anywhere in Java. *Methods* run on threads.

The aforementioned lifecycle methods are called on the main application thread, regardless of whether or not there is an activity in the foreground, or even if an activity exists.

> Then If I declare Handler in service as well as activity what would happen?

You would have an instance of `Handler`.

> Because a single Thread has one instance of Handler

The default behavior of `Handler` is to tie itself to the main application thread, no matter whether you create a `Handler` in an `Activity` or a `Service`.

Comment: so if my service start a thread and i want a communication channel like this: Thread can send data to service and service can send data to activity. if the service and activity handlers are bound with the application handler then which handler will receive the message if thread sends a message to  service?

Comment: @KanwarSaad: The message will go to the `Handler` on which you called `sendMessage()`.

Comment: Its not working .. so what im doing is that made a handler in activity as well as in service. Passed the service handler to a new thread. Thread then sends a message to service using that handler. I copy the received message to another message and then send it to UI using the UI handler. This give me androidruntimeexception: this message is already in use.

Comment: @KanwarSaad: Then perhaps you should consider other techniques for communicating between components, such as sending commands to services with `startService()`, or using `LocalBroadcastManager`, or using a third-party event bus like Otto. Regardless, your current problems are not related to your original question. If you want somebody to help you debug your use of `Handler`, ask a new StackOverflow question, including the code that you are using and the stack trace showing the exception.

Comment: thanks .. I'll mark this answer as right because it answered most of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

From [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services):

> A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service
> does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process
> (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is
> going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3
> playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the
> service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce
> the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the
> application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
> with your activities.